# .htaccess and making urls friendly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All I want to do is remove a section of my urls, i assume that this is the easiest way.

This is how my URLs currently look:

```
subdomain.domain.com/site/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=$postTile
```

I want to remove:

```
?action=viewArticle&url=
```

So that I end up with something like:

```
subdomain.domain.com/site/blog/$postTitle
```

I've tried the below, but I've had no joy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^ subdomain.domain.com/site/bwc/(blog)/(.*)/$   /bwc/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=$2
```

Please help - I think I need to utilise MOD_REWRITE, but I'm not too sure how. 
I also need a solution that will allow the friendly URLs to be linked too - can .htaccess/apache do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule  ^site/bwc/blog/(.*?)/$ site/blog/?action=viewArticle&url=$1
```

But note that in this case your urls will **always** have to end with a `/` for this to work

What the rewrite rule does is basically php's `str_replace` on the URI. It will run the regular expression you provide on the request URI and replace it with the replacement you have also given. To have a better understanding you need to be good with Regular Expressions, that some say are a language all by themselves. `(.*?)` is a capture group in regex. Capture groups can be accessed as `$\d` in replacement strings where `\d` will be the consecutive number of the capture group in the pattern.

Long story short if you send a request that matches the regex pattern it will grab it, do the replacements and send that to the server, instead of the address you entered.

Comment: Just to be clear - how does it work?

Does that line of code tell the server to take whatever comes after '/blog/' and to put it on the end of blog/?action=viewArticle&url= and then bring back the result?

Comment: That's awesome - thanks for explaining that. If I had enough rep I'd up-vote your answer!

Comment: @php_nub_pp - just out of interest - is there a way to do it without the need for the trailing '/' ? I'm worried that may create problems with external backlinks breaking - should they ever be put in place..

Comment: @Jack Ofc you just remove the slash from the end of the pattern